Why do some license agreements ask for the signee's date of birth?
E.g. I see that the Llama 3.1 Community License Agreement asks for the signee's date of birth. Why do some license agreements ask for the signee's date of birth?

Ability to contract
People of all ages want to buy products. However, children and teenagers are not allowed to engage in all contracts and enforcement of contracts can be limited. As such, asking for the Date of Birth allows not to contract with them based on their limited ability to form contracts.
Identification
Assume that there are 2 people called John Doe in a town. The chance that they are born on the same date is small. Together with address, this can lead to a positive "This but not that person" in case of litigation.
Child Protection Laws
Material such as pornography, alcohol, or tobacco may not be made available to children. Asking for the date of birth is an attempt to limit the liability of the offering party.

This also protects the company from liability for distributing inappropriate content to minors, which might have ended up in the LLM training materials, and is hard for the company to predict since LLMs are basically a "black box" that even its creators don't fully understand.

Since the form specifically states that you are agreeing to share your contact information with the repository's author, Meta, I would wager that the primary concern is compliance with regulations like the Children's Online Privacy Protection Rule (COPPA).  Meta (then Facebook) has dealt with several different FTC complaints about privacy and their use of personal information from minors.  I would expect that Meta's lawyers want to ensure that any time they gather personal information from people that they know the age of those people lest they inadvertently monetize information from minors.
